# How to call and what means: _DWORD *__thiscall

Tags: ida, c++, game-hacking, calling-conventions

I have one question maybe you can help, I always find this functions in IDA:

```
void __thiscall sub_79340(_BYTE *this, int a2, int a3, int a4)
```

And I use them like this:

```
// talkChannel
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _talkChannel)(DWORD localplayer, uintptr_t mode, uintptr_t channelId, const std::string& message);
_talkChannel talkChannel;
talkChannel = (_talkChannel)(moduleBase + 0x79340);

talkChannel(LocalPlayerPointer, 1, 0, "hello world");
```

But this time I find this in IDA:

```
_DWORD *__thiscall sub_142860(_DWORD **this, _DWORD *a2, int a3)
```

I understand the first definition (return void, calling convention thiscall, address of function X, pointer to this as it's a thiscall, parameters)... but I can't understand the second one :(

I don't know how to call this... Anyone could help me explaining what it means and how to use it? I would like to understand the difference between both

Thanks for your time <3

Answer (score 1):

Basically I've checked with Ghidra to compare and I've found that the signature is different:

```
void __thiscall FUN_00142860(int param_1_00,undefined4 *param_1,int param_2)
```

So, basically I just declared the function this way:

```
// get tiles
typedef void(__thiscall* _getTiles)(DWORD map, TileList* buffer, uintptr_t floor);
_getTiles getTiles;
getTiles = (_getTiles)(moduleBase + 0x142860);
```

So, double check with other tools and don't rely only in IDA output.